# Mordell curves with many integral points

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, mordell-curves

For $k\in{\mathbb Z},k\neq 0$, denote by $f(k)$ the number of integral points on the Mordell curve $y^2-x^3=k$. According to the data at http://tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp/simath/MORDELL , the largest value of $f$ on the interval $[-10000,10000]$ is 32, attained for $k=1025$.

Is it known/conjectured whether $f$ can take arbitrarily high values ?

Answer (score 7):

The largest value for $f(k)$ that I know of is an example due to Noam Elkies with
$k = 509142596247656696242225$, where there are (at least) $125$ pairs of solutions (so $f(k)=250$ in your notation). If ranks of elliptic curves over the rationals are absolutely bounded, then so is $f(k)$ (as long as one restricts to $6$th power free values of $k$ to avoid trivial scaling). Nothing is provable at this point, however.

Comment: so you can just take a curve with rank $\ge 1$, look at $n$ rational points, make the product of the denominators, raise it to the $6$th power and multiply $k$ with that to get a curve with $n$ integral points

Comment: Yes, that would be trivial scaling.